# How to create maven web application using intellij IDEA 12?

Tags: java, maven, web, intellij-idea

Can you explain me What steps I can make for creating maven web application using idea 12?

Comment: 1)  Create POM with appropriate dependencies for your specific project.  2)  Import dependencies via the Maven Projects tab.  That's about it...unless there was something else to it that you were looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

idea simply is a web application. you can use web archetype and regular maven dependencies mechanism 
check this tutorial 
     http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects